# Are anonymous struct declarators legal in Ansi C?

Tags: c

I assume something like this cast is legal (where foo is a pointer to void) :

```
struct on_off {
                  unsigned light : 1;
                  unsigned toaster : 1;
                  int count;            /* 4 bytes */
                  unsigned ac : 4;
                  unsigned : 4;
                  unsigned clock : 1;
                  unsigned : 0;
                  unsigned flag : 1;
                 };

((on_off) foo).count = 3;
```

But I'm wondering if the struct is *not* defined whether something like this is legal :

```
((struct {
                  unsigned light : 1;
                  unsigned toaster : 1;
                  int count;            /* 4 bytes */
                  unsigned ac : 4;
                  unsigned : 4;
                  unsigned clock : 1;
                  unsigned : 0;
                  unsigned flag : 1;
         }) foo).count = 3;
```

... or something along these lines.

Thanks!

Comment: There are several problems with `((on_off) foo).count = 3;`. (1) `on_off` is undeclared; the type you declared is `struct on_off`. (2) You can't cast to a struct type. (3) A cast-expression is not an lvalue, so it can't be on the LHS of an assignment. I think what you mean is `((struct on_off*)foo)->count = 3;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, C allows casting to anonymous structures. Here is a quick demo:

```
struct xxx {
    int a;
};
...
// Declare a "real"struct, and assign its field
struct xxx x;
x.a = 123;
// Cast a pointer of 'x' to void*
void *y = &x;
// Access a field of 'x' by casting to an anonymous struct
int b = ((struct {int a;}*)y)->a;
printf("%d\n", b); // Prints 123
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/DgyW18).

Comment: Thanks... would you say that with anonymous declarators there are no limitations? In other words, if it can be declared then it can be anonymous right?

Comment: @Anthony Right, there are no additional restrictions on the anonymous structures.