# C - get type alignment portably

Tags: c, types, alignment, portability

I'm writing really small interpreter for a very simple language, which allows for simple structure definitions (made of other structures and simple types, like int, char, float, double and so one). I want fields to use as little alignment as possible, so using max_align_t or something similar is out of question. Now, I wonder if there is a nicer way to get alignment of any single type other than this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define GA(type, name) struct GA_##name { char c; type d; }; \
    const unsigned int alignment_for_##name = offsetof(struct GA_##name, d);

GA(int, int);
GA(short, short);
GA(char, char);
GA(float, float);
GA(double, double);
GA(char*, char_ptr);
GA(void*, void_ptr);

#define GP(type, name) printf("alignment of "#name" is: %dn", alignment_for_##name);

int main() {
GP(int, int);
GP(short, short);
GP(char, char);
GP(float, float);
GP(double, double);
GP(char*, char_ptr);
GP(void*, void_ptr);
}
```

This works, but maybe there is something nicer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>This is probably not very portable, but</strike> GCC accepts the following:

```
#define alignof(type) offsetof(struct { char c; type d; }, d)
```

**EDIT:** And according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800462/1956010), C allows casting to anonymous struct types (although I'd like to see this statement backed up). So the following should be portable:

```
#define alignof(type) ((size_t)&((struct { char c; type d; } *)0)->d)
```

Another approach using [GNU statement expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440021/compiler-support-of-gnu-statement-expression):

```
#define alignof(type) ({ \
    struct s { char c; type d; }; \
    offsetof(struct s, d); \
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the best solution is:

#define alignof(type) ((size_t)(offsetof(struct { char c; type d; }, d)))

It avoids &*0, which is nice, since I'm pretty sure I read that this isn't exactly safe, and althought it works, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: casting a *pointer* to *null* to a `size_t` is really horrible, and definitely not portable. Even the null pointer bit pattern *itself* need not be zero. The best you could do is to calculate the *difference between* two char pointers in the struct, this would result in `ptrdiff_t` whose value actually *has* some backing in the standard.

Comment: This is undefined behavior since it dereferences a null pointer.

Answer (score 12):

There is in C11, which adds `_Alignof`:

```
printf("Alignment of int: %zu\n", _Alignof(int));
```

It is usually better style to include `<stdalign.h>`, and use the lowercase `alignof`:

```
#include <stdalign.h>

printf("Alignment of int: %zu\n", alignof(int));
```

You can check for C11 this way:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
    /* C11 */
#else
    /* not C11 */
#endif
```

If you're using GCC or CLang, you can compile your code in C11 mode by adding `-std=c11` (or `-std=gnu11` if you also want GNU extensions). Default mode is `gnu89` for GCC, and `gnu99` for CLang.

---

## Update:

You might not need to check the alignment for your system at all, if you make a few educated guesses. I would recommend using one of these two orderings:

```
// non-embedded use
long double, long long, void (*)(void), void*, double, long, float, int, short, char

// embedded use (microcontrollers)
long double, long long, double, long, float, void (*)(void), void*, int, short, char
```

This ordering is perfectly portable (but not always optimal), since the worst-case scenario is just that you get more padding than otherwise.

***What follows is an (admittedly lengthy) rationale. Feel free to skip everything past this point if you don't care how I came to this conclusion for the ordering.***

---

### Covering most cases

This holds true in C (regardless of implementation):

```
// for both `signed` and `unsigned`
sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
sizeof(float) <= sizeof(double) <= sizeof(long double)
```

With a bit of tinkering with the order, you should be able to get unpadded structures in *most* cases. *Please note that this does **not** guarantee that the structure will be unpadded; but it will be in **most real-world** cases, which should be GoodEnough™.*

*What follows is advice that is implementation-specific, but should cover alignment in **most** cases.*

This is, however, perfectly portable everywhere (even if not optimal) — as long as you accept that there may be some padding (in other words, don't assume the structure is without any padding). If you get it wrong, all you'll get is a larger structure, so there's no danger of hitting undefined behavior of any kind.

What you should do is order these from largest to smallest, since their alignment will also be in this order. Assuming a typical amd64 compiler:

```
long long a; // 8-byte
long b;      // 8-byte or 4-byte; already aligned in both cases
int c;       // 4-byte; already aligned
short d, e;  // 2-byte; both already aligned
char f;      // 1-byte; always aligned
```

#### Integer types

So let's start figuring out our order, starting with integer types:

```
long long, long, int, short, char
```

#### Floating-point types

Now, the floating-point types. What do you do with `double`? Its alignment is *typically* 8 bytes on 64-bit architectures, and 4 bytes on 32-bit (but it can be 8-byte in some cases).

`long long` is always at least 8-byte (this is implicitly demanded by the standard because of its minimum range), and `long` is always at least 4-byte (but it's *usually* 8-byte in 64-bit; there are exceptions such as Windows).

What I would do is put `double` between those. Note that `double` can be 4 bytes in size (usually in embedded systems, such as AVR / Arduino), but those practically always have a 4-byte `long`.

`long double` is a complex case. Its alignment can range from 4-byte (say, x86 Linux) to 16-byte (amd64 Linux). Nevertheless, 4-byte alignment is a historical artifact and is suboptimal; so I'll presume it's at least 8-byte and put it above `long long`. This'll also make it optimal when its alignment is 16-byte.

This leaves `float`, which is practically always a 4-byte quantity, with 4-byte alignment; I'll put it between `long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 4-byte, and `int`, which can (typically) be 4 or 2-byte.

All of this combined gives us the next order:

```
long double, long long, double, long, float, int, short, char
```

#### Pointer types

All we have left now are pointer types. Size of different *non-function* pointers is not necessarily the same, but I am going to assume it is (and it is true in the vast majority of, if not all, cases). I'll assume function pointers *can* be larger (think hardware architecture with larger ROM than RAM), so I'll put them above others.

Worst-case *practical* scenario is that they're the same, so I've achieved nothing; best-case is that I've eliminated some more padding.

But what about the size? This typically holds on *non-embedded* systems:

```
sizeof(long) <= sizeof(T*) <= sizeof(long long)
```

In most systems, `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(T*)` are the same; but e.g. 64-bit Windows has 32-bit `long`, and 64-bit `T*`. However, in embedded systems, it's different; pointers there can be 16-bit, which means:

```
sizeof(int) <= sizeof(T*) <= sizeof(long)
```

What to do here is up to you --- *you* are the one who knows where this'll usually run. On one hand, optimizing for embedded where primary use is non-, means optimizing for the uncommon case. On the other hand, memory is more limited in embedded systems than not. Personally, I'd recommend optimizing for desktop use, *unless* you're specifically making an embedded application. Since the alignment of `double` is typically the same as pointer size *but can be larger*, I'd put this below `double`.

```
// non-embedded
long double, long long, void (*)(void), void*, double, long, float, int, short, char
```

For embedded uses, I'd put it below `float`, since alignment of `float` is usually 4-byte, but `T*` is 2-byte or 4-byte:

```
// embedded
long double, long long, double, long, float, void (*)(void), void*, int, short, char
```

Comment: I'd gladly use C11 features, unfortunately due to some business/technical restraints I'm forced to stay in the realm of C89/C90 (yup, old compilers on old machines). Anyway, I'm giving +1 since it will be nice to use it once these shackles are broken.

Comment: @JędrzejDudkiewicz: I've greatly expanded my answer now, with an ordering that should *usually* work. Most of the update is just rationale though, so that you can see my reasoning behind it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a nice discussion. To be honest I'm not quite sure what should I do with it, since I specifically asked how to get alignment and best answer was provided by nwellnhof. At the same time what you wrote is useful and certainly insightful - can I somehow assign more than single "point" to your answer or is there no way to do it?

Comment: @JędrzejDudkiewicz: I don't think there is any way to do it, but don't worry about it. Thanks anyways!